# Adding forwarders with IIS over windows

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7, iis-6, iis-7.5

Is it possible to add a forwarder using IIS on Windows?
I know it can be done with cPanel but i'm not sure if it can be done on Windows.

I am trying to run an email piping system.
Thanks.

Comment: Get thee to the daemons of server fault!

Comment: What do you mean with it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about something like an SMTP forwarder?  We may be able to better answer your question if you can explain a little more clearly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, that's it.
I am trying to make the pipping system work but i can not follow the official documentation as it is based only on Unix:
http://docs.accord5.com/Email_Piping

I am trying to do what it explains on the point: Configuring cPanel (X3 skin)

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible under windows ii7?

Comment: The SMTP service is not a part of IIS7.  There is an SMTP service that ships with Server 2008 and Server 2008R2 and it requires that you install the IIS 6 Management Compatibility feature since the SMTP service requires the inetinfo.exe process to run and uses the IIS 6 Management console.  If you can figure out how to configure the SMTP service to work properly to send email you should be able to use it as a forwarder, however it really isn't a part of IIS - it just piggybacks on it for a place to run and a configuration interface.